# Gradle integration test in Kotlin with Java project

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, integration-testing

I have a Gradle project written in Java. I want to set up integration tests in Kotlin.
For that i used JVM Test Suite Plugin as described [here](https://tomgregory.com/gradle-integration-tests/). Gradle version is 7.5.1
When i try to build the project, it fails with:

```
BUILD FAILED in 2s
14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date
slawomir.filip@polpc10555 myproject_backend % ./gradlew integrationTest

> Task :compileIntegrationTestKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/BaseIT.kt: (3, 41): Unresolved reference: repository
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/BaseIT.kt: (19, 15): Only 'const val' can be used in constant expressions
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/BaseIT.kt: (19, 16): Unresolved reference: BackendApplication
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/BaseIT.kt: (19, 16): An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/BaseIT.kt: (32, 40): Unresolved reference: OptionsJpaRepository
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/domainoptions/GeneralInfoControllerSpec.kt: (6, 41): Unresolved reference: dto
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/domainoptions/GeneralInfoControllerSpec.kt: (7, 41): Unresolved reference: repository
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/domainoptions/GeneralInfoControllerSpec.kt: (16, 35): Unresolved reference: OptionsEntity
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/domainoptions/GeneralInfoControllerSpec.kt: (17, 35): Unresolved reference: OptionsEntity
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/domainoptions/GeneralInfoControllerSpec.kt: (18, 35): Unresolved reference: OptionsEntity
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/domainoptions/GeneralInfoControllerSpec.kt: (22, 24): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: /Users/slawomir.filip/Documents/custom/myproject_backend/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/myproject/backend/domainoptions/GeneralInfoControllerSpec.kt: (22, 58): Unresolved reference: GeneralInfoDto

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

for this example test:

```
package com.myproject.backend.domainoptions

import org.amshove.kluent.shouldBeEqualTo

import com.myproject.backend.BaseIT
import com.myproject.backend.domainoptions.dto.GeneralInfoDto
import com.myproject.backend.domainoptions.repository.entity.OptionsEntity
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus

class GeneralInfoControllerSpec : BaseIT() {

    @Test
    fun `should test something`() {

        optionsJpaRepository.save(OptionsEntity("sth1", "14"))
        optionsJpaRepository.save(OptionsEntity("sth2", "11"))
        optionsJpaRepository.save(OptionsEntity("sth3", "T"))
        val response = makeGetRequest("/options", GeneralInfoDto::class.java)

        response.statusCode `shouldBeEqualTo` HttpStatus.OK
    }
}
```

Gradle doesn't see project internal dependencies (as for example: OptionsEntity) and I don't know why.

Structure of my project is:

```
- src
  - integrationTest
    - kotlin
    - resources
  - main
    - java
    - resources
  - test
    - java
    - resources
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.3.3.3'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.0'
}
group = 'com.myproject'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
apply plugin: 'application'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies { /* my dependencies */ }

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true"]


compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}



configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

testing {
    suites {
        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            dependencies {
                implementation project
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn testing.suites.integrationTest
}


apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
```

Is it even possible to do this? To have kotlin tests for java project?
If yes, what do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
sources {
                java {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/integration/kotlin', 'src/integration/resources']
                }
            }
```

so the result is

```
testing {
    suites {
        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            dependencies {
                implementation project
                annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
            }
            sources {
                java {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/integration/kotlin', 'src/integration/resources']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the good approach, but it works